# k8s network policy block to instance metadata seems to allow anyway

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, egress

I'm looking to block pod access to the instance metadata service via network policies. The VPC CNI now [supports network policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-vpc-cni-now-supports-kubernetes-network-policies/) and my cluster uses it (v1.14).

What's perplexing is that blocking all egress traffic with the following policy works but...

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-egress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

the policy below does not (taken from [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-eks-best-practices/issues/84)). From within the pod, I can still curl to the IP address.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-metadata-access
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 169.254.169.254/32
```

suggestions as to why one works and the other doesn't are welcome

Tried different policies. As noted before, block all egress works, but a particular IP range does not.